# Low events entries not listing events

Tags: low-events

Not sure i am doing something silly.

I want to list all events from a specific day using low events.
So i have this:

```
{exp:low_events:entries channel="events" date="2014-06-26"}
```

I would expect this to return all events for that day.

I have one event with low events fields set to:
2014-06-26 - 2014-06-28 (all day ticked)

Should i see the one event?

Comment: What are your fieldtype settings? If "Overwrite entry date" is set to Yes, you should also add `show_future_entries="yes"` to the Entries tag.

Comment: That was it. Told you it was something silly i was doing!

Comment: 'Kay. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your fieldtype settings. If "Overwrite entry date" is set to Yes, you should also add `show_future_entries="yes"` to the Entries tag.